# C# Post construction

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm using the `sqlite` framework for windows phone applications to create system classes based on my database tables.
I've expanded my system classes to include datatype properties that cannot be stored in the `sql` database.

Therefore I wish to set these properties after the construction of my classes, based on the input I receive from the database tables.

Is there a way invoke a method (Post constructor) immediately after the object of my class has been instantiated without making use of inheritance?

```
- Database Table (TestSubject)
- Id : Integer
- A : Integer
- B : Integer

- System Class (TestSubject)
- Id : Int
- A : Int
- B : Int
- C : Int //(Can I set this after the construction of the TestSubject object?)
```

Say I wanted to set C to be equal to A + B, I would have to wait for A and B to be set to do this though.

Comment: so you set in the constructor A and B why cant you set C in the constructor also as c=a+b ?

Comment: sqlite automaticly sets ID, A and B through ORM to reflect the database tables into system classes.

Comment: Can't you just create a property that does this for you? `public string ABCombined { get { return A + B; } } `

Comment: The property could in fact do it for me. I'm not sure it will be sufficient in all cases, but it certainly is in this one. Thank you.